# ActionController::Parameters - Permit method does not return parameters for nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I have a little problem. Can you tell me why permit method cannot return data_set_users_attributes and data_set_synch_agents_attributes in second example from code below? This is weird. All data looks fine, permit arguments too. Both parameters_hash are send from this same form and both permit data are created by this same function.

EDIT: I use Ruby 2.3.0 and rails 4.2.4

```
require 'rails/all'
# Params passes
_permit = [
    "configuration_id",
    "max_packages_on_server",
    "reports_synch_interval_min",
    {
        "data_set_users_attributes" => [
            {
                "0" => [
                    "user_id",
                    "send_alerts",
                    "_destroy"
                ]
            },
            {
                "2015_09_09_15_21_50" => [
                    "user_id",
                    "send_alerts",
                    "_destroy"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data_set_synch_agents_attributes" => [
            {
                "0" => [
                    "synch_agent_id",
                    "max_idle_on_data_set",
                    "_destroy"
                ]
            },
            {
                "2015_09_09_15_21_51" => [
                    "synch_agent_id",
                    "max_idle_on_data_set",
                    "_destroy"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

parameters_hash = {
    "action" => "create",
    "commit" => "Save",
    "controller" => "data_sets",
    "data_set" => {
        "configuration_id" => "",
        "data_set_synch_agents_attributes" => {
            "0" => {
                "_destroy" => "false",
                "max_idle_on_data_set" => "-1",
                "synch_agent_id" => "1"
            },
            "2015_09_09_15_21_51" => {
                "_destroy" => "",
                "max_idle_on_data_set" => "-1",
                "synch_agent_id" => "2"
            }
        },
        "data_set_users_attributes" => {
            "0" => {
                "_destroy" => "false",
                "send_alerts" => "1",
                "user_id" => "1"
            },
            "2015_09_09_15_21_50" => {
                "_destroy" => "",
                "send_alerts" => "1",
                "user_id" => "2"
            }
        },
        "max_packages_on_server" => "",
        "reports_synch_interval_min" => ""
    }
}

params = ActionController::Parameters.new(parameters_hash)
p params.require(:data_set).permit(_permit)

# Params not passes
_permit = [
    "configuration_id",
    "max_packages_on_server",
    "reports_synch_interval_min",
    {
        "data_set_users_attributes" => [
            {
                "0" => [
                    "user_id",
                    "send_alerts",
                    "_destroy"
                ]
            },
            {
                "1" => [
                    "user_id",
                    "send_alerts",
                    "_destroy"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data_set_synch_agents_attributes" => [
            {
                "0" => [
                    "synch_agent_id",
                    "max_idle_on_data_set",
                    "_destroy"
                ]
            },
            {
                "1" => [
                    "synch_agent_id",
                    "max_idle_on_data_set",
                    "_destroy"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

parameters_hash = {
    "action" => "create",
    "commit" => "Save",
    "controller" => "data_sets",
    "data_set" => {
        "configuration_id" => "",
        "data_set_synch_agents_attributes" => {
            "0" => {
                "_destroy" => "false",
                "max_idle_on_data_set" => "-1",
                "synch_agent_id" => "1"
            },
            "1" => {
                "_destroy" => "false",
                "max_idle_on_data_set" => "-1",
                "synch_agent_id" => "2"
            }
        },
        "data_set_users_attributes" => {
            "0" => {
                "_destroy" => "false",
                "send_alerts" => "1",
                "user_id" => "1"
            },
            "1" => {
                "_destroy" => "false",
                "send_alerts" => "1",
                "user_id" => "2"
            }
        },
        "max_packages_on_server" => "",
        "reports_synch_interval_min" => ""
    }
}

params = ActionController::Parameters.new(parameters_hash)
p params.require(:data_set).permit(_permit)
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you need to try this:

```
params.require(:data_set).permit(
  :max_packages_on_server,
  :reports_synch_interval_min,
  data_set_synch_agents_attributes: [:synch_agent_id, :max_idle_on_data_set, :_destroy],
  data_set_users_attributes: [:send_alerts, :user_id, :_destroy])
```

to get parameters for updating your model.

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/5mxv2s.png <- look at this picture from my console. I generate a params like yours using my method named "generate_permit_arguments" with argument :update and tried get parameters using get_data_set_params. In next step i tried do this with options from my first post and it still does not work. Last i just print params variable.

It does not work with rails 4.0 and above. Ruby is installed from rvm.

Comment: Can you give the full output of `generate_permit_arguments`? And what is your model in more details?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/R1bNZFaA - here is my code. Models and controller method "generate_permit_arguments"